# Changed records since last export

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Im trying to figure out the best way to do delta exports using SSIS. I have a set of tables in a database that should be exported to a set of files at daily interval. I will have to export ONLY new and altered records. In each table there is a field called **LastEdit** that holds the date when the record was last edited (or created).

So my initial thought was to have a new table with something like **"id","Jobname", "LastRun"**. Now whenever i export a table using a SSIS job, i will write the date of the run in this table along with the job name. And then next time i have to export data i will look in this table and find last run date and only export records newer than this.

Im fairly new to SSIS so im thinking if this is the best way or if there are some build in functionality for doing this, or if someone have a better design pattern for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried two cool tools of Sql Server? CDC and Change Tracking? They are availables from 2008 R2 version

Answer (score 1):

SSIS + Change Data Capture is designed exactly for this.

Comment: Looks very nice! But will this have function to track when i last did export? As far as i can see, this will still require me to set in what interval i want changes. What im looking for is a way to automatically export rows from a table that changed since i last exported that table into a file

Comment: Is this an ETL/data warehouse process?  if so, and you are wanting to use SSIS you need to provide CDC with a point in time so it knows what data to send you.  You can store the timestamp any way you want, then you can tell CDC where to get it from so it can return to you the right data.  Here's more info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: Hi Greg, What i was looking for was if there where any functionality that would handle the "last export" date for me. But it looks like i will have to create a table or similar to save that, so that i know from where in time i should sync data. Thanks for the input